# bootstrap data-toggle="popover"not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the code provided by the bootstrap page http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage and for some reason I cannot get the popover boxes to work. Can someone please help. Here is my plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/ojSNWiSXOOSUw8xhehp4?p=preview

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on left
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on top
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on bottom
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on right
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use popover not as Angularjs directive you have to enable them

```
$(function(){
$('button').popover()
});
```

please see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/kZMsITSss22v19pbc0Zo?p=preview

if you want use popver using angular UI Bootstrap please see demo here:http://plnkr.co/edit/BB7V60qIgoo4D5U8igzb?p=preview

Comment: How do you set the size of the popover using the angular UI bootstrap. Your example works correctly but when the text is really large, it goes everywhere. Can you please reply.

Comment: @user3799365 are you sure ? http://plnkr.co/edit/BB7V60qIgoo4D5U8igzb?p=preview click bottom

Comment: Yes please add lot more text to your message and you will see it will come out of the popover dialog

Comment: @user3799365 http://plnkr.co/edit/BB7V60qIgoo4D5U8igzb?p=preview still looks fine for me how much more text do you want to include in popover ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Bootstrap JS features you need to convert them to Angular directives.

*AngularUI Team* has already done that, so you just need to use [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), and in this particular case, their [popover](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) directive.

Comment: Thanks I could mark your answer as accepted since the above answer is also complete and I marked that. It lets you only choose one